# Не могу применить метод к динамически созданному элементу

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

Имеется определённый список:

```
<ul id="products">
        <li class="product">Андрей</li>
        <li class="product">Николай</li>
        <li class="product">Саша</li>
        <li class="product">Ярик</li>
    </ul>
```

И форма, которая добавляет элементы в этот список:

```
<form action="#">

    <input type="text" id="dataProduct">
    <button onclick="addProduct()" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Проблема в том, что я создаю элементы `.product` по нажатию на `button`. И эти созданные элементы не возможно потом найти используя метод `.eq()`, будто у них нет индекса, а индексы есть только у тех четырёх пунктов `li`, которые изначально есть в `DOM html`.

Вставка элемента происходит так:

```
$(".product").eq(index).before("<li сlass='product'>" + product + "</li>");
```

Comment: "Вставка элемента происходит так:", а поиск как происходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй создать элемент перед вставкой и все будет работать

```js
$(function() {

  var Products = (function() {
    var self = this;


    this.init = function() {
      this.add();
      this.show();
    };

    this.add = function() {
      $('button').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var liElem = $('<li></li>', {
          class: 'product',
          text: $('#dataProduct').val(),
        });
        $(".product").eq(2).before(liElem);
      });
    };

    this.show = function() {
      $('.show').on('click', function() {
        $.each($('.product'), function(i, v) {
          $('.result').append('<p>' + 'ТЕГ li' + ' : ' + $(v).text() + '</p>');
        });
      });
    };

    self.init();
  }());

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="products">
  <li class="product">Андрей</li>
  <li class="product">Николай</li>
  <li class="product">Саша</li>
  <li class="product">Ярик</li>
</ul>

<form action="#">

  <input type="text" id="dataProduct">
  <button onclick="" type="submit">submit</button>
</form>

<input type="button" class='show' value="print">

<div class="result">

</div>
```

Comment: Действительно, если создать элемент тем способом, который Вы предложили - поиск по индексу работает правильно. Но почему поиск элементов, созданных вашим способом, работает, а если мы непосредственно добавляем элемент `$(".product").eq(index).before("<li сlass='product'>" + product + "</li>");` - индекс находит неверно